# Compare multiple lists to contain the same data

Tags: c#, compare, fileinfo

I have a list of Machines that have a property of type `List<FileInfo>`. Here is the definition.

```
internal class Machine
{
    internal string MachineName { get; set; }
    internal List<FileInfo> Files { get; set; }

    internal Machine(string machine)
    {
        this.MachineName = machine;
        this.Files = new List<FileInfo>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Machine - {0}", this.MachineName);
    }
}
```

The code populates the list from servers on my network, each server should have identical files with identical versions, if they don't, I need to know about them.

How would I compare multiple `Files` lists (up to four at once if it matter) pragmatically using C#?

This would be easy if there were just two machines to compare to (for example using `Distinct`) and indeed I can compare all lists to one. But is there some way to compare all at the same time?

Comment: This question is a little hard to answer because it's not completely clear what you're wanting to do.  However; if you want to compare any list of anything you can use linq but you need something to compare it to.  What are you looking for exactly in the comparison?  Can you send a quick line of code showing the comparison logic and from there I believe I could give you the logic I would use to compare a list.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534334(v=vs.110).aspx).

All you need to do is flatten the file lists ([`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx)), group by `FileInfo` and assert that all groups have `n` files, `n` being the number of machines you are verifying:

```
var areAllIdentical = machines.SelectMany(m => m.Files)
                              .GroupBy(f => f, myComparer)
                              .All(g => g.Count() == n);
```

`myComparer` is there because you'll probably need to implement your own equality logic for `FileInfo` when grouping; the default behavior will most likely not meet your requirements, can't check it out right now, but my guess is that its reference equality.

What makes two `FileInfo` be considered the same? Same file name, last written date, etc.? Implement that logic in a custom [`IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) and you are set.